# sudo in pbuilder environment to install

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb, pbuilder

I try to build a PPA for Ubuntu of PJSIP including python bindings:

```
pbuilder-dist raring build pjproject_2.1-2.dsc
```

To install the bindings the command (executed by make install)

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

needs to be executed. Without *sudo* the command fails due to file restrictions.

I added *sudo* to the build dependencies, but for some reason a password request is opened.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the usage *sudo* is not necessary, if the package is configured correctly.
I needed to add the folders, where **python setup.py install** needs access, to debian/*install files.... and use `--install-layout=deb --root=debian/tmp`

[During pbuilder build: run setup.py --install-layout=deb fails (no rights to write to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754968/during-pbuilder-build-run-setup-py-install-layout-deb-fails-no-rights-to-wri)

Then the access permission are set correctly.

Just use dh_install correctly.